# How to display a variable only after a specific time

Tags: php

```
<?php

ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/New_York');

require_once '../init.php';

$dates = ['2015/11/29 21:28:00'];

$tz = $_POST['tz'];

$timestamp = strtotime("+1week");

$one_week = date("Y/m/d G:i:s", $timestamp);

$key = array_search($one_week, $dates);


if($tz == 'est'){

  if(false !== $key){

    echo html_escape($dates[$key]);

  }

}elseif($tz == 'pst'){

   if(false !== $key){

    $old_date = strtotime($dates[$key]);

    $new_date = strtotime("-3 hour", $old_date);

    $date = date("Y/m/d G:i", $new_date);

    echo html_escape($date);

}

 }elseif($tz == 'cst'){

if(false !== $key){

    $old_date = strtotime($dates[$key]);

    $new_date = strtotime("-1 hour", $old_date);

    $date = date("Y/m/d G:i:s", $new_date);

    echo html_escape($date);

}

}elseif($tz = 'mst'){

  if(false !== $key){

    $old_date = strtotime($dates[$key]);

    $new_date = strtotime("-2 hour", $old_date);

    $date = date("Y/m/d G:i:s", $new_date);

    echo html_escape($date);

   }

}

?>
```

What the above code is doing is ultimately feeding a date, according to which link was pressed, whether it be est, pst, cst, or mst, to javascript through an ajax request for a timer, if there is a match. The only way there would be a match is if the current date and time +7 days matches a value in the array, but I realized something.... I made it to strict. Let me explain what I mean by "too strict". Lets say that in the array of dates and times there is a value 2015/11/21 20:30:00 and the current date and time is 2015/11/21 20:30:01, the above code wont make a match. What I need to know is how to allow the above code to make matches as long as it after 20:30:00 and not before. I hope that I explained well enough.

Comment: you can match only date...

Comment: darn, thx anyways :(

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what that code is doing, but it sounds like you should be able to just convert both dates to UNIX timestamps and do a simple integer comparison on them. That would also simplify all the strange timezone conversion you're doing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maxton for giving me a hint. I finally got what I was looking for!!!!
I turned the current date and time into a timestamp using strtotime and the current date and specific time into a timestamp and did a integer comparison. While still taking into account the timezone difference.

Code for future readers:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');

$cur_time = strtotime(date("Y/m/d G:i:s"));

$time = strtotime(date("Y/m/d 13:55:00"));

if($cur_time > $time){

    echo 'Yeah!!';

}else{

    echo "Boo!!";

}
```